# Flutter Firebase offline issues with await

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

When I try to reorder things in my reorderable list view, I run into a problem. If the user is online, awaiting the document references (as seen in the code) runs fast enough. The problem is, if the user is offline, the Firebase await function can take upwards of 20 seconds. On the other hand, if I don't await these changes, and do multiple quick reorders, the resulting writes as soon as I go back online differ greatly from the "order" state that I have in the app.

Is there anything I can do that avoids awaiting?

I have thought about checking the online status and disabling this feature while offline or disabling the reorder function while the function awaits. Both seem like really bad solutions.

Thanks for the help, the code is below:

```
Future<void> reorderExercises(int oldIndex, int newIndex,
          CollectionReference<AddExercise> whereToUpdateRef) async {
    
        

List<DocumentReference<AddExercise>> referenceList = [];


    await whereToUpdateRef.orderBy(COLUMN_DAYSINDEX).get().then(
          (value) => value.docs.forEach(
            (element) {
              referenceList.add(element.reference);
            },
          ),
        );


    void _updateIndex(int _oldIndex, int _newIndex) {
      referenceList[_oldIndex].update(
        {COLUMN_DAYSINDEX: _newIndex},
      );
    }

    if (oldIndex < newIndex) {
      newIndex -= 1;
      _updateIndex(oldIndex, newIndex);
      for (int i = oldIndex + 1; i <= newIndex; i++) {
        _updateIndex(i, i - 1);
      }
    } else {
      for (int i = oldIndex - 1; i >= newIndex; i--) {
        _updateIndex(i, i + 1);
      }
      _updateIndex(oldIndex, newIndex);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem:**

`await` is very slow when the user has no internet on

---

**Solution:**

You check if the user has internet. if not you push to a `noInternet()` screen with a try again button.

You can check if the user have internet with this code:

```
   Source _source = Source.serverAndCache;

    try {
            final result = await InternetAddress.lookup('example.com');
            if (result.isNotEmpty && result[0].rawAddress.isNotEmpty) {
                 _source = Source.serverAndCache;

            }
          } on SocketException catch (_) {
                 _source = Source.cache;

          }
    
    firebaseDocumentReference.get(GetOptions(source: _source))...
```

This is very close to Liam's answer, but I cannot edit it unfortunately.
Using his code I changed the source option and now offline await works as fast as online. Also changed "google.com" to "expample.com" for it to work in China as well.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem:**

`await` is very slow when the user has no internet on

---

**Solution:**

You check if the user has internet. if not you push to a `noInternet()` screen with a try again button.

You can check if the user have internet with this code:

```
var haveInternet;

  ...

    try {
            final result = await InternetAddress.lookup('google.com');
            if (result.isNotEmpty && result[0].rawAddress.isNotEmpty) {
              haveInternet = true;
            }
          } on SocketException catch (_) {
            haveInternet = false;
          }
```

---

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What exactly are my options when the user is offline? Displaying a Progress Indicator for the time that the await takes blocking any interaction? Couldn't I also just do this with a variable that marks the start and end of the db function, basically blocking the screen if it takes longer than half a second for the function to return?
If I just use a noInternet() screen that would mean that the app only works online right? My whole point in using FireStore was to have offline persistence. Thanks again

Comment: Yes if you use an noInternet() screen it will mean that the app doesn't work without internet and if you do not use the way with the no Internet screen you need to show a progress indicator. sorry

Comment: This is unfortunately not an option, the app has to work offline. FireStore supports it, I think I just have to display a progress indicator until it returns.
Do you think checking for internet connection and if disconnected using the source: cache is an option? How about when syncing back online later?

Comment: If you use the progressIndicator-way, you don't need to check if the user has internet, you always show the progress indicator when something is loading. Then it is optional if the user has internet.

Comment: yes, but the point is that it works while it's offline, but just slower. I think I will try your solution to check for internet and if there's no connection I will use source: cache for my firestore get requests and see how that goes, thanks